# sin(), cos(), log10() (float) not found for target thumbv7em-none-eabihf

Tags: rust, embedded, cortex-m

I'm using Rust 1.51 and this minimal crate:

```rust
#![no_std]

fn main() {
    let a = 2.0.cos();
}
```

I'm building it with `cargo check --target thumbv7em-none-eabihf` and the compiler complains with this message: `no method named 'cos' found for type '{float}' in the current scope`. Same for `sin()` and `log10()`.

I found https://docs.rust-embedded.org/cortex-m-quickstart/cortex_m_quickstart/ and I would expect the above message for targets `thumbv6m-none-eabi` or `thumbv7em-none-eabi` but not for `thumbv7em-none-eabihf` which has FPU support.

How can I solve this?

Comment: you want to use std function but ask to not include std. There is obvious a problem in your logic

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2505

Comment: thanks, I didn't know these are only in `std` but not in `core`

Comment: please create a self answer when you solve it that question will be helpful for a lot of future reader I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rust 1.51 (and below) functions like `sin`, `cos`, or `log10` are not part of the core library (`core::`) but only the standard library (`std::`), therefore they are not available.

A practical solution is to use the crate `libm` which offers typical mathematic functions for `no_std`-environments.

```rust
#![no_std]

fn main() {
    let a = libm::cosf(2.0);
}
```

See:

- libm crate: https://crates.io/crates/libm
- Discussion to move math functions to core library https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2505

Comment: Be aware, though, that libm does **not** contain hardware acceleration, even if the target platform would support it. This isn't relevant for `sin()` or `cos()` for `thumbv7em-none-eabihf`, because its FPU does not support those, but for example `abs()` or `sqrt()` are supported and will be a lot slower with `libm`. More information can be found in the [rfc discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2505) already linked in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

What @phip1611 said is correct, `cos` is no longer part of the core library and hence not usable in `no_std` out of the box. You can use `libm` directly OR via a std friendly wrapper using the `num-traits` crate with the `libm` feature enabled. This lets you write no_std code as you would write std code. E.g.

```
# cargo.toml
num-traits = { version = "0.2", default-features = false, features = ["libm"] }
```

And then in your code:

```
#![no_std]

#[allow(unused_imports)]
use num_traits::real::Real;

fn main() {
    let a = 2.0.cos();
}
```